# Pygame in PyCharm (or Visual Studio)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Where am I going wrong about with Pygame in PyCharm??

1 I have installed Pycharm and its works

2 I have installed Python and Pygame.  I have ran "python -m pygame.examples.aliens" in the cmd and the game loads.

3 I have anaconda3 on my computer and that works i.e. you can use the files in the library

4 When I go to Pycharm and type "import pygame" I get an error line

5 So I try and change the interpreter to where Pygame is located and it does not work.

How do you get Pygame into an interpreter.  Or what the hell am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package will be available only for the version you've installed, python2 or python3.
It looks like you installed pygame into python2, if this command works in cmd:

```
python -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

To check or change the default interpreter used in PyCharm:

-menu File > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > 
Python Console > Python Interpreter

By modifying this **you don't change the interpreter** in your current projects, you can create a new project to check if Pygame is working now.

In your current projects, you can see what interpreter is enabled, in the top right corner toolbar:

-name of the file > Edit configurations > Python interpreter

---

Maybe you can install Pygame in Python3 to avoid the issue

Comment: Thanks 
I was looking at this area last night but did not have the sense to change Anaconda to Python 3.6.1
So, the actions I took were:

-menu File > Default Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console > Python Interpreter

In the Python Interpreter I changed the D:\Anaconda\Python.exe to D:\Python\Python.exe